# Python Script Fail when folderpath contains a space

Tags: python

I have a python script that works well unless the folder path contains a space. How can I enable my script to still work when the folder path has a space within it.

```
sourceS3Bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
sourceS3Key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
sourceS3 = 's3://'+ sourceS3Bucket + '/' + sourceS3Key
destinationS3 = sourceS3
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try using `os.path.join` instead of joining the strings using `+`. if that doesn't work, consider creating a minimal, reproducible example : https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Hi Rob O'Brien, could you please provide more code and the error message that you are getting? I think I may have an idea about what is going on